# Docker network interfaces names inside docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-container, docker-network, network-interface

i am using docker to run application that requires multi network interfaces,
i create new networks using docker network create, and i see that new networks created on my host.
When i do docker run, i use --network to connect the docker container with the chosen network. My problem is that on the host the network interface is called “cvd-ebr” (with is what i want) but inside the docker container is called “eth0”, with cause me problem with the application.

Any way to setup the network interfaces names inside the container ?
The network type is Bridge.

thanks

I try to use docker run with --network name=my-net,iface=my-iface but i get error invalid key iface. I also try to use com.docker.network.bridge.name: my-iface when i create the network.
what i want is the network interface on the host and inside the container will have the same name, without using --network host.

Comment: What is your application doing, that the network interface names matter?  Normally Docker will fully manage the containers' network environment, so it's normal for your container to see only `eth0` and `lo` interfaces but nothing else, even if the host is multi-homed.  Do you need to run this application directly on the host, not in an isolated network environment?

Comment: The application is using android emulator that requires specific names because it's changes the IP tables. Running it's on the host it's working, but does it less secure? i was surprise that i can't control the network interfaces inside the container